# android - Geocoder.getFromLocationName() is not working in ICS device

Tags: android, geocoding, android-maps

I have two devices. One is **HTC WildFire S** and other one is **HTC 1V**. I used the `Geocoder.getFromLocationName()` in my application. It is running successfully in the **HTC wildfire S**. But in the **HTC 1V** i got the following error. why it's came? How can i solve this? please can anybody help me.

Code

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault()); 
//s is the address
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(s, 5); //Here i got the following Exception.
```

**Error**

```
06-18 16:28:17.933: W/System.err(4960): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
06-18 16:28:17.953: W/System.err(4960):at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
```

**Location Tab**

[image]

Comment: That's just a warning that the geocoder is not available, have you got Internet access setup on the One V? The Geocoder needs Internet access to retrieve the result. EDIT: Your app isn't crashing at this stage is it?

Comment: Yes, i have the internet permission.

Comment: Yes but does the device have connectivity? Can you browse the web on the device at the time of your testing?

Comment: Are the location services in settings clicked on? On SGS II ICS they are here : Settings>Locations services. The options in there must be  clicked on.

Comment: i added the location service tab. plz refer that.

Answer (score 6):

Finally i found the answer :https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009

Reboot your device for Geocoder to work. Hope it helps someone

Note: some say it will work if you use Google API 16

Comment: This error was coming in Google Map API V1.. i have tried it on Google Map v2.. with some syntax change of course and it works might well on all android device.
Note: For Google MAp V2 you no longer need to import Google APIs

Comment: In my app with V2 Map it doesn't work... What kind of import do you refer to?

Comment: in the end it still doesn't work... even with API 16. how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -2):

```
  GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (LATITUDE * 1E6),
                        (int) (LONGITUDE * 1E6));

String n;

public void someRandomMethod() {
        n = convertPointToLocation(point);
}



public String convertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {
        String address = "";
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6,
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                    address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return address;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just provide code for your answer. Why is this is *the* answer?