# Geocoder not working ICS but works in Gingerbeard

Tags: android, google-maps, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Well i have made a application that uses Google Maps.

I am currently using Tap on Map to get the address through Geocoder but it is not working.

I have tried the code in Gingerbeard e.g HTC chacha, Samsung Galaxy S2(Gingerbeard) it works well and get the address but fails to get the address in ICS

Yes i have used Google API 14, have uses all permissions, also used declare the google maps library in Manifest.And also have the proper keystore keys

I tried the Google Sample Code Examples
e.g: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/currentlocation.html

HTC DESIRE X, ICS:

[image: HTC DESIRE X, ICS]

HTC CHACHA Screen shot:

[image: HTC CHACHA Screen shot]

how should i solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098983/android-geocoder-getfromlocationname-is-not-working-in-ics-device

Got this Question but it is unanswered. Kindly help me solve this

Comment: can any one suggest me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (LATITUDE * 1E6),
                        (int) (LONGITUDE * 1E6));

String n;

public void someRandomMethod() {
        n = convertPointToLocation(point);
}



public String convertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {
        String address = "";
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6,
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                    address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return address;
    }
```

Comment: Finally i found the answer :https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009

Reboot your device to Geocoder to work. Hope it helps someone

Comment: I faced this problem too after check this thread my issue was solved. "Finally i found the answer :code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009 Reboot your device to Geocoder to work. Hope it helps someone – Araib karim". Thanks Araib karim